# Binding setTimeOut to some function with specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a notification pop up, each pop up is dynamically generated after ajax fetched the data.
The pop up each will have a time limit of 10 seconds before it fade out. Something like you see on Facebook's notifications on the left bottom corner.
Each pop up will be hidden according to the time it is added and the timelimit.

Here's an example of my code:

```
function hidePop(obj){
  $(obj).hide();
}

function newpopup(data){
    $('#notifications').prepend('<li class="new" style="display:none;">'+data+'</li>');
    $('.new').fadeIn(200, function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       $(this).removeClass('new');
       setTimeout(function(){
          hidePop($this)
       }, 10000);
    });
}
```

As you can see above, my AJAX call will call for newpopup with the data. Once it fades in completely the setTimeout function will run.
This works, however, after a few more li is appended, those new lis will keep hiding itself once its showed.
Note: I remove class new once everything is done since new will then be used for the latest incoming popups.

I think the setTimeOut is either not stopped or targeting all of the lis.

Is my method a problem or is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply prepending an `<li>` tag as a string that states a class, then selecting the class with jQuery, I would suggest using the DOM to create the `<li>` element and hold a reference to it like so:

```
function hidePop(obj){
  obj.hide(); //obj parameter already wrapped by jquery, no need to do it again
}

function newpopup(data){
    var newLi = $(document.createElement("li")); //createElement then wrap jQuery around it
    newLi.html(data).css("display", "none"); //jQuery set innerHTML and CSS

    $('#notifications').prepend(newLi); //Prepend to list

    newLi.fadeIn(200, function() { //Select this and only this li element
       setTimeout(function(){
          hidePop(newLi); //Closure; reference to the same "this and only this li"
       }, 10000); //10s
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the body of the anonymous function in setTimeout, `$this` is overwritten. Try this:

```
function newpopup(data){
    $('#notifications').prepend('<li class="new" style="display:none;">'+data+'</li>');
    $('.new').fadeIn(200, function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       $(this).removeClass('new');
       var thatPopup = $this;
       setTimeout(function(){
          hidePop(thatPopup)
       }, 5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: "In the body of the anonymous function in setTimeout, `$this` is overwritten." No, that's incorrect. Were you thinking of `this`? `$this` is a local variable just like `thatPopup`, and the closure preserves references to both of them in the same way. Adding the `thatPopup` variable won't change anything.